# LinkedBlockingQueue using Comparator

Tags: java, queue, comparator

I'm using a `LinkedBlockingQueue` to share some object between threads.
The problem is that I can have some duplicates in this queue. 
I have tried this  solution:

```
SortedSet<ResultInsert> set = new TreeSet<ResultInsert>(new MyComparator());
set.addAll(bulkInserts);
```

and implemented:

```
@Override
    public int compare(ResultInsert arg0, ResultInsert arg1) {

}
```

For some reason it seems that it does not compare  each element from my collection with all the elements.
For instance I have 61 elements and it eliminates some duplicate and I have 51 elements, except that between this 51 there are some more duplicates.

I just did a test : for 61 objects it calls compare 342 times, 351 times,.. not every time the same number of times. 
I logged all and I don't get it. It does not compare all.

Anyone any idea, please? Since this morning I'm trying to solve this and I cannot go further.

Comment: There isn't going to be an easy way to address this issue.  You _might_ try a `Maps.newSetFromMap(ConcurrentHashMap)` to approximate a `ConcurrentHashSet`, and then use that in combination with a queue...but I would spend an hour or two trying to avoid all these problems by _allowing_ the duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can of course make your own subclass which prevents insertions of duplicates, by overriding `put` and just ignore the call if the given element exists in the queue.

```
class NoDupBlockingQueue<T> extends LinkedBlockingQueue<T> {
    @Override
    public void put(T e) throws InterruptedException {
        if (!contains(e))
            super.put(e);
    }
}
```

If you really need to use a `Comparator`, it could be written like this:

```
class NoDupBlockingQueue<T> extends LinkedBlockingQueue<T> {

    Comparator<T> comp;

    public NoDupBlockingQueue(Comparator<T> comp) {
        this.comp = comp;
    }

    @Override
    public void put(T e) throws InterruptedException {
        for (T e2 : this)
            if (comp.compare(e, e2) == 0)
                return;
        super.put(e);
    }
}
```

Note that adding an element to the queue becomes a linear operation. You would have to maintain a separate data structure (such as a HashSet) if you would like better performance.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried but for some reasons it does not works. For some reason it does not eliminate the duplicates. No I'm trying something else. From ArrayList to build a HashSet and do addAll(). I'm using my own comparator, but I don't get it. It does not compare all the elements. It eliminates some, but not all. I tried to log all and it seems that it does not compare all the elements between them.

Comment: You can't use a Comparator with HashSet. You need to rely on hashCode / equals.

Comment: You mean that I must use something else instead of a treeSet with my custom comparator ?